# How to check if a file exists in R with a variable in file path

Tags: r

How would I go about finding if a file path exists, if I have a variable within a file path?

```
month = format(Sys.Date()-32, format = "%Y-%m")
dir = file.path("Some:\\Path\")
ec = file.path(month)
tory = file.path("\continued.csv")

if (file.exists(dir,ec,tory)){
    print('TRUE')
} else {
    print('FALSE')
}
```

I am trying to see if "Some:\Path\2020-09\continued.csv" exists. If I were to run this next month, it would search for "Some:\Path\2020-10\continued.csv"

Comment: Typo  `Sys.Date`  not `Sys.date`

Comment: One way to do this is `file_name -> file.path("Some:", "Path", month, "continued.csv")` and then use `file.exists(file_name)`. Just make sure the date format matches your directory structure.

Comment: depending on the date you run this, you might skip a month, so subtracting by month would be safer, compare these two: `d <- as.Date('2020-10-01'); format(d - 32, format = "%Y-%m"); format(seq(d, length.out = 2, by = '-1 months')[2], '%Y-%m')`

Comment: Alternative to `d-32` is `seq.Date(Sys.Date(), by = "-1 month", length.out = 2)[-1]`. A little safer when the starting day-of-month is 1-2 (or Mar 4).